# Display on mobile hide on Desktop Button/link

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a click-to-call link in my webpage i have the following

```
<a class="mobile-only" href="tel:+534306464456"><p class="">Click Here to call us</p></a>
```

I want it to only display on mobile devices phones specifically 
in my css i tried

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .mobile-only {
        display:block !important;
    }

}
.mobile-only{
    display:none !important;
}
```

but it does not work is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

```
.mobile-only {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
    .mobile-only {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: its definitely working paste this or if you want to tab than change max-width.

Comment: This does not work the link is still displaying on desktop

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Only move .mobile-only class to above to your media query, remenber that is **cascading** style sheet, this mean that media query will be place at the end of the file, or instead you can place .mobile-only inside of a media query that only affect desktop resolutions. By the way avoid using !important statement in your css.

```
.mobile-only{
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .mobile-only {
        display: block;

    }
}
```

Other approach will be:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .mobile-only {
        display:block;

    }

}
@media only screen and (min-width: 991px) {
     .mobile-only{
         display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would advise against saturating your code with !important statements.

Comment: Sorry @vladko13, I  forgot remove it in my answer. updated it

Comment: @AlbertoLinares Thanks for the answer but the link is still displaying

Comment: I have updated my answer, try any of the different approach

Comment: @AlbertoLinares tried both still the same i even tried making 2 diffrent <a> tags but it doesnt work.

Comment: I have added my first approach in fiddler and works fine, you can see in https://jsfiddle.net/yr65kamx/

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
.mobile-only {
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    .mobile-only {
        display: none;
    }
}
```